# what's the relationship about memory controller && channel && DIMMs?

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture

I'm reading Computer Architecture, A Quantitative Approach'. And what's the relationship about memory controller && channel && DIMMs?

> If the instruction is not found in the L3 cache, the on-chip memory controller must get the block from main memory. The i7 has three 64-bit memory channels that can act as one 192-bit channel, because there is only one memory controller and the same address is sent on both channels (step 14). Wide transfers happen when both channels have identical DIMMs. Each channel supports up to four DDR DIMMs (step 15). When the data return they are placed into L3 and L1 (step 16) because L3 is inclusive.

Comment: [How much of ‘What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory’ is still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47714514) - most of it, including the low-level stuff about DRAM layout; I think it covers dual-channel controllers and how multiple DIMMs can be attached to each controller aka channel, and how the commands work to stream data from different banks and/or DIMMs to get high utilization of the channel it controls.